# Can STL algorithms be used with circular lists?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Creating an STL compliant iterator for your custom list is pretty mundane.

Yet, if the reffered list is a circular one, it seems quite pointless since all STL algorithms are operating on a `[first, last)` range and in a circular list `first = last`.

**Is there a standard/consice way to overcome this obstacle** and have STL algorithms operate on "home made" circular lists ?

I'm supposing defining STL compliant iterators is the first step to this goal, but a solution that would operate on ranges might also be possible.

---

I need to implement this for a plethora of "home made" structs. My current solution is to derive from `boost::iterator_facade` and then create a custom `range` class (like [Rudolph's](https://github.com/klmr/cpp11-range)) and use any algorithm wrapped around range-based execution. Still this has some logical obstacles and would like to see alternatives and or solutions that worked out.

Comment: This will only work if you define an `end()` in a circular list. If you are able to do that, and iterating from `begin()` gets you there, I don't see any problem.

Comment: You could have two different kinds of iterators, one that implements the wrap-around and the other implementing the usual semantics.

Comment: You'll find a major obstacle to this is circular lists have context-dependent ideas of what "first" and "last" are. Starting at two different locations in the list as "first" will wield two different "last" concepts. It sounds trivial, but in practice it can get messy quick.

Comment: Take a look at `boost::circular_buffer` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html).

Answer (score 4):

You will need custom iterators, but the solution can still be range-based.
One possibility is that `begin()` could return a specially marked iterator (flag `initial=true`) so that it knows that it hasn't made the round yet. `end()` would return an iterator with that flag set to false. Then `operator++` would set the flag to false, so that `begin()` won't be equal to `end()`. You could use a different marking scheme as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this works well only for 'read only' iterators. The basic problem with this approach is that during an iteration, the initial node might be deleted, so *both* `begin()` *and* `end()` may be invalidated, and `end()` cannot be re-evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of STL and its iterators is inconsistent with your proposition. Iterators in the C++ standard library (as it is now known) have the semantics of pointers. They do not wrap, and `end()` is not equal to `begin()`.

As pointer analogues, iterators point to a location in a buffer. You cannot expect a linear copy operation by a naive caller to wrap around at the end. This will apply through the algorithm and other libraries. They will simply not work as expected, as far as I can see.

I see no reason at all why you should not use STL collections and iterators, but I don't think you should expect (or force) `it++` to wrap. I rather think you need clearly visible member functions that implement the additional functionality you require.

For example, you could have a `incr()` function that increments an iterator, but if it points to `end()` wraps to the beginning. You could have a `copy()` function that understands how to extract or insert a block of data in a buffer that wraps.

But then I don't understand your other constraints, so this might not work for you. I think it would work for me.

Comment: Surely, you cannot expect a linear copy operation to work on all containers? Take a linked-list or a map for example.

Comment: @Skizz: I could probably express that better, but `copy(first,last,result)` will certainly not work if `first===last`.

Answer (score 0):

Said that in many algorithms (I'm not talking about STL, but in general) a null-leaf(s) or null element(s) is(are) inserted in the internal data structure in order to improve performance, I feel like keeping an empty/null element in your circular list can make the trick.

- The null element is not fixed in position, obviously, and it will move according to your data flow.
- At the same time you'll keep the last N sample in your data struct (size N + 1 empty element) contiguous.
- That makes feasible a range `[first,last)` where `first != last`.
- The null element is the one pointed by last, and it's where the next insertion will take place.
- At every insertion, once N elements are in the container, the element pointed by `first` is "nullified", and `first` incremented.

Hope this may help.